# How to Setup Software RAID 1 with FDE & Different Size HDDs

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, raid, mdadm

My boot drive is using 22.04. Here's what I want to accomplish:

I have two HDDs, one with 6TB and the other with 8TB capacity. They'll be storage drives, not boot drives. I want to create a software RAID1 using both drives that's 6TB in capacity. I want it to have full disk encryption, as well as have FDE on the spare 2TB partition on my 8TB drive that can't be used for the RAID1.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you running into problems? What guide are you following?

Comment: Does RAID allow specification of a _partition_, or just whole disk volumes? If the former, partition the 8TB as a 6TB partition and a 2TB partition. I'm to lazy to look, given the smount of detail in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

It took me awhile, but I answered my own question. I'll write this so people new to Ubuntu like me can follow along on Ubuntu 22.04. Before you continue, make sure all data that you want to keep that is currently on either drive being used in the RAID1 array is backed up to another drive.

In the lower left of your Dock Panel, click the Show Applications button, then search for Disks and open the program. Find both drives on the left of the window that you wish to use for your RAID1 array and delete all pre-existing partitions on both of them, if there are any, by selecting each partition and pressing the red (-) button. Select your smaller drive and press the gear button, then click 'Format Partition'. Use the default options which will be ext4 un-encrypted, then click 'Next'.

Take note of what drive letters are assigned to each of your drives, in Disks under Device. For example in correlation to the Question, I'll use '/dev/sdaX' as the 8TB drive, and '/dev/sdbX' as the 6TB drive. Substitute your own drive letters whenever I use those two drive names in my examples.

Open a terminal and enter the following command to see exactly how large the sole partition on your smaller drive is.

`sudo parted -l`

Now you can see where the partition starts, and where it ends (partition size). You'll now make a partition on your larger drive that's exactly the same size as the partition on your smaller drive. I'll use my 8TB and 6TB drives I setup as an example in the following steps. Enter the following commands to setup a gpt partition table, substituting your own drive letters to point to your larger drive.

`sudo parted /dev/sdaX`
`select /dev/sdaX`
`mklabel gpt`

For the following command, substitute the '6.0TB' below with the maximum partition size of your smaller drive obtained from the first command you entered.

`mkpart primary ext4 1MB 6.0TB`

Save and quit parted.

`quit`

Check that you have a partition on your larger drive that is exactly the same size as the sole partition on your smaller drive.

`sudo parted -l`

Create the RAID1 array for the two same-size partitions that you want to use, substituting 'sdaX' and 'sdbX' below with your own drive letters.

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install mdadm cryptsetup`
`sudo mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdaX /dev/sdbX`

Now your RAID1 array volume will be visible in Disks, just like a normal drive. In Disks, select your RAID array on the left-hand side of the window, then press the gear button. Click 'Format Partition', enter whatever name you want for it, then check the box 'Password protect volume (LUKS)' then click 'Next'. Enter your desired encryption passphrase in 'Password' and 'Confirm' then click 'Next'.

Now your RAID1 array is fully encrypted. You can also format the Free Space on your larger drive and encrypt that as well using the methods above. If you've never utilized a boot drive with a separate encrypted storage drive (encrypted RAID1 array in this case), take note that you'll have to unlock it each time you boot by opening Files, '+ Other Locations' in the lower left, then clicking on your storage device.

Another option is in Disks click the gear button on your encrypted storage device and press 'Edit Encryption Options', uncheck 'User Session Defaults', and enter the encryption passphrase so your device will unlock on startup. If your boot drive is unencrypted though, that would obviously render the encryption of your storage device useless. If you go that route, your boot drive's encryption passphrase strength should be equal to that of your storage drive's passphrase to keep your data safe.